# Netbeans codeigniter debugging waiting for conection and showing error :Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, codeigniter-3, netbeans-8

I am trying to debug my web application in Netbeans 8.2 IDE,Edited `php.ini` file

```
xdebug.idekey = netbeans-xdebug
;these added for enable debugging
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

When I start debug application netbeans IDE always return error

```
 Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. 
To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings. (21:51:29:544 | null)
  at https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=277385395761685&domain=localhost&origin=1&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2
  Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FXBwzv5Yrm_1.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df1fc1f79c67e25%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ff1653a707e61948%26
  relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey:1
```

**In this project i did't used any facebook related things**.Then why it is showing  `https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?`

What i am doing wrong.

Comment: where application debug break? is debug starts? check project property

Comment: Netbeans always showing `waiting for connection(netbeans-xdebug)`.Application launched in chrome,No break point hit.